# Search select item in DropdownList with replacement keywords (ASP.NET/ JS/ JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a problem with search the item on dropdownlist/ or select option by using input text. I have a dropDownList

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="list">
                <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Mr" Value="Mr"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="I" Value="I"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="II" Value="II"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="III" Value="III"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<select id="list">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Mr">Jr</option>
                <option value="I">II</option>
                <option value="II">III</option>
                <option value="III">IV</option>
</select>
```

How can I search the option III when i click on dropdownlist and input "3".It mean checks to allow variations of the same value.For example, when input Mr,MR,mR,mr.,mr,MR.,mR.  the dropdownlist focus to item have value= "Mr".
When input "I" or "1" the dropdownlist focus the item have value ="I".
Does anyone have an idea? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: i can't not detect the event input keypress when i click on the dropdownlist. By default, the dropdownlist filter/ search item by first character if type input and focus this item. How can i change that event? :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some logic to convert integer to Roman numerals. Something like this:

```
public static string ToRoman(int number)
{
    if ((number < 0) || (number > 3999)) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("insert value betwheen 1 and 3999");
    if (number < 1) return string.Empty;            
    if (number >= 1000) return "M" + ToRoman(number - 1000);
    if (number >= 900) return "CM" + ToRoman(number - 900); 
    if (number >= 500) return "D" + ToRoman(number - 500);
    if (number >= 400) return "CD" + ToRoman(number - 400);
    if (number >= 100) return "C" + ToRoman(number - 100);            
    if (number >= 90) return "XC" + ToRoman(number - 90);
    if (number >= 50) return "L" + ToRoman(number - 50);
    if (number >= 40) return "XL" + ToRoman(number - 40);
    if (number >= 10) return "X" + ToRoman(number - 10);
    if (number >= 9) return "IX" + ToRoman(number - 9);
    if (number >= 5) return "V" + ToRoman(number - 5);
    if (number >= 4) return "IV" + ToRoman(number - 4);
    if (number >= 1) return "I" + ToRoman(number - 1);
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("something bad happened");
}
```

You can use int.Tryparse for checking whether user has actually entered a number or not then you can use this method.

Comment: i can't not detect the event input keypress when i click on the dropdownlist. By default, the dropdownlist filter/ search item by first character if type input and focus this item. How can i change that event? :( –

Comment: I think you have a textbox for search so based on the user's input you should search that into the list of data you have and then you should select that value in the dropdown. Is this your need let me know if I missed anything?

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, my dropdownlist  is same the link : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select
that only tag select option, not have the text field for the input.

Comment: @FollowYourHeart then you can not implement custom search into that I would suggest you use https://www.fourthbottle.com/2015/03/how-to-create-searchable-dropdown-list.html